# Symfony 2 and FOSUserBundle - add information from path to User during registration

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have a Symfony 2 application making use of FOSUserBundle.  The app will be used by members of a number of different organisations, and I'd like them to be able to go to an organisation-specific URL in order to register, for example `http://www.myapp.com/[organisation_name]/register`.  How can I let FOSUserBundle handle the registration, but also add `[organisation_name]` to the User record it creates?

My research suggests I might need to hook into a FOSUserBundle event (`REGISTRATION_SUCCESS`?), but I'm not sure about the exact mechanics of that or getting info from the URL.

[FOSUserBundle Events](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/controller_events.md)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GET` attribute, like this:

```
http://www.myapp.com/register?org=acme
```

Event subscriber, in this case, will look like this:

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Event;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;

class EventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            'fos_user.registration.success'  => array('onRegistrationSuccess', 10),
        );
    }

    public function onRegistrationSuccess(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getUser();
        $org = $event->getRequest()->query->get('org');
        $user->setOrganisation($org);
    }
}
```

And don't forget to register your subscriber in `services.yml`:

```
acme_demo.event_subscriber:
    class: Acme\DemoBundle\Event\EventSubscriber
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this.  One of the key requirements is that the URL is very tidy, and the organisation is very prominent.  Is there a nice way of extracting [organisation] out of `http://www.myapp.com/[organisation_name]/register` (rather than your querystring proposal) from within the subscriber?  A little research suggests I could read it from the URL directly, but it would be nicer to be pre-parsed.  The rest of your example looks perfect.

Comment: Right, had a little look into this.  Seems like the best solution would be to arrange for my EventSubscriber to also be passed the @router service, and then just let the [Router](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/introduction.html) parse the URL just like it would normally, spitting out the parameters.

Comment: @frumious There are many ways to do it. I just suggest an idea. So you can play with it like you need ;)